# R Shiny render plots asynchronously as soon as they are ready

Tags: r, shiny

From the code block below, is possible to render plotlyOutput("users") asynchronously / completely independently from plotlyOutput("apps")?  Right now I have to wait for both of them to complete all processes to render the final shiny app as a single monolithic output.  Ideally all visuals have 'withSpinner' loading icons and load independently.

I looked at future/promises trying to wrap the renderPlotly statements with future({ code }) but could not get that working and ended up being not sure if that was the right path.

Note: the df "rsc_usage" is loaded from a .feather file in S3---I omitted that code

```
### PULL IN REQUIRED LIBRARIES
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(aws.s3)
library(DT)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(tidyr)
library(feather)
library(shinycssloaders)


ui = dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(
    disable = FALSE,
    title = "Customer Activity",
    titleWidth = '100%'
  ),

  dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
  dashboardBody(tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                            tabPanel(
                              'Analytics',
                              fluidRow(
                                column(6, plotlyOutput("users") %>% withSpinner(color = "#0dc5c1")),
                                column(6, plotlyOutput("apps") %>% withSpinner(color =
                                                                                 "#0dc5c1"))
                              )
                            )))
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$users <- renderPlotly({
    ggplotly(
      rsc_usage <- rsc_usage %>%
        group_by(username) %>%
        summarise(visits = n()) %>%
        arrange(desc(visits)) %>%
        head(15) %>%
        ggplot(., aes(
          reorder(username, visits),
          visits,
          text = sprintf("username: %s<br>visits: %s", username, visits)
        )) +
        geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
        coord_flip() +
        theme_minimal() +
        labs(y = "Number of page visits",
             x = NULL) +
        ggtitle("top users")
      ,
      tooltip = c("text")
    )
  })

  output$apps <- renderPlotly({
    ggplotly(
      rsc_usage <- rsc_usage %>%
        group_by(name) %>%
        summarise(visits = n()) %>%
        arrange(desc(visits)) %>%
        head(15) %>%
        ggplot(., aes(
          reorder(name, visits),
          visits,
          text = sprintf("name: %s<br>visits: %s", name, visits)
        )) +
        geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
        coord_flip() +
        theme_minimal() +
        labs(y = "Number of page visits",
             x = NULL) +
        ggtitle("top content")
      ,
      tooltip = c("text")
    )
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```